# How to get overview of shared library dependencies

Tags: java, shared-libraries

We have several hundred microservices running on many tomcat servers. Common for all these tomcat servers and microservices is the use of a common library containing shared business logic.

When we change logic in the shared library, we sometimes break some microservices, even though we ensure backwards-compatible changes. We lack overview of which service is using which shared class.

The question is not about regression testing, but more about give the developer overview of impact of changing shared logic.

What is the best way to get this overview ?

We are using Eclipse, Java 8, RTC (jazz.net), Tomcat, Windows, Cygwin, Ant.

We could use Eclipse reference search, however this requires us to check out all microservices into the workspace and then let Eclipse resolve all references (which will take 10+ minutes)

It would be a preference to have a tool within Eclipse to avoid using external tools to get this overview.

I am not sure if it has to be a real-time search or if we find it sufficient to use documentation generated by a job ran in scheduled intervals.

What would you suggest ?

PS My need is part of the [static program analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) practice.

Comment: Do you mean the change in the common library introduces a new, 3rd party jar dependency which is not deployed for some services which now need it?  If yes, consider using maven (instead of ant) which automatically detects those 3rd party dependencies and will include them in the war.

Comment: no, that is not what I mean. We have a fix number of predefined libraries  and are not adding more. 

Imagine we have service A and service B using shared library C. Developer checks out service A and C and modified C and commits the changes. The changes to C has now broken B.

I need a way for developer to know that changes to C will impact B, therefore developer should checkout B also and verify his change is still functional for B. See also my edit and the wiki link for more info.

Comment: What does _broken_ mean?  Assuming a compile error then: 1) the existing method in C is marked as deprecated and a new method is created, and A is updated to to use the new method. Static analysis should be able to identify the code using a deprecated method to help create a road map to update B and any other services to the new method.  2) Or when change to C is committed this should trigger a build.  Once C build is complete this should trigger a build for all other services using C.  B should fail and people are notified. A build failure is **not** a bad thing.

Comment: Broken is irrelevant to my question, but could be a compilation error or a data related error. I am more after how the developer can identify the dependencies at code time. If we only had 10 services, we could check all 10 out in Eclipse and do a reference search before changing shared logic, but when we have several hundred services that is not an option. The important part here is to understand where we are on the timeline, this is during development, not during regression testing or when the code is running in production.

Comment: Other than a method signature change, why should the developer have to care?  Are the shared methods doing too much?  For example, the shared method get all the data, while the specific service filters the data as needed.  I realize this is not helping to answer your question, but I am wondering if the focus needs to shift.

Comment: Example: Shared logic contains a method  which takes a data object as input and returns a data object as output. The shared method implementation performs queries against a shared database. A developer checks out a service (that is not performing well) and the shared logic and changes (optimizes) the query (in the shared method). He then tests his own service and confirms everything is working and commits all his changes. The optimization of the query however broke another service which were using some other properties in the output object, which now contains incorrect data values.

Comment: If the original developer had a tool to see what other services uses this shared logic, then he could have tested the change on all services or notified the other service owners of this change prior to delivery of the change.

Comment: Why would optimized code change the result?  There should be unit and/or integration tests to catch unintended changes when code is optimized.